# External USB HD does not get recognized after Windows start - only after plugin it out and in first

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

When I start Windows, my external USB hard disk does not appear at all:
[image]

When I unplug and plug it in again, it appears normally and stays that way:
[image]

What I checked already is that Windows does a clean shutdown/start by uncheking the fast startup:

[image]

Unforunately that does not help. I also unchecked that Windows might power down this specific USB port:

[image]

At last, I also deactivated selective energy saving for USB in the energy settings:

[image]

The USB hard disk also does not show up in Disk Management nor USB Tree Viewer nor the BIOS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I am running out of options what to do. **Any ideas how I can make Windows recognize this hard disk right from the start?**

Comment: You have done most of the troubleshooting by yourself. I also eager to know the answer.

Comment: Have you done any other troubleshooting steps like trying a different USB port? Also, next time you start up the computer and the drive isn't showing up, run disk management and see if the drive is detected in there.
I assume your drive is powered via USB?

Comment: Just for curiosity sake, does the drive show up in your EFI firmware settings (aka BIOS) at boot without plug/unplug?  This sounds more like a firmware bug to me than anything else.  Also, before unplug/replug, try [this tool](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview.html) and see what it shows.  Bonus!! Es ist auf Deutsch!  If the USB tool can't see it, windows can't either.

Comment: @NetServOps I have not tried a different USB port, I can do that. However, I had my previous USB disk at the very same USB (3) port... it does not get recognized in disk management either (see additional screenshot in the description)... yes, via USB

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'll check the BIOS next time I reboot. The disk does show as "not connected" with the USB Tree Viewer (added screenshot)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I did not see the USB drive show up in the BIOS, however, not sure if it should show, since the BIOS is quite old (screenshot added)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I did not find any firmware update for my drive on https://www.seagate.com/de/de/support/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/expansion-portable/ (S/N: NAC25CA9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried these two steps suggested (among many others) on https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/usb-device-not-recognized/, and one (or both) of them solved my issue:

1. After having replugged the USB device, I ejected it properly, disconnected it and connected it again
2. I uninstalled all hidden USB devices