# USB harddisk does not get recognized by Windows anymore

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb

Just a few days ago, Windows did recognize my quite new USB disk (also on my second pc and smart tv) - with some issues however: [External USB HD does not get recognized after Windows start - only after plugin it out and in first](https://superuser.com/questions/1658422/external-usb-hd-does-not-get-recognized-after-windows-start-only-after-plugin).

Now, since today, Windows does not recognize the disk anymore. Neither does Windows disk management. It does get listed in the device manager, however:

[image]

When I check with USB Tree Viewer, I can see the disk showing up with the following details:

```
    =========================== USB Port2 ===========================

Connection Status        : 0x01 (Device is connected)
Port Chain               : 1-2

      ========================== Summary =========================
Vendor ID                : 0x0BC2 (Seagate Technology LLC)
Product ID               : 0x231A
USB version              : 2.10
Port maximum Speed       : High-Speed
Device maximum Speed     : SuperSpeed
Device Connection Speed  : High-Speed
Self Powered             : no
Demanded Current         : 500 mA
Used Endpoints           : 5

      ======================== USB Device ========================

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Device Description       : Per USB angeschlossenes SCSI (UAS)-Massenspeichergerät
Device Path 1            : \\?\USB#VID_0BC2&PID_231A#MSFT30NAC25CA9#{2accfe60-c130-11d2-b082-00a0c91efb8b} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_STORAGEPORT)
Device Path 2            : \\?\USB#VID_0BC2&PID_231A#MSFT30NAC25CA9#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE)
Kernel Name              : \Device\USBPDO-16
Device ID                : USB\VID_0BC2&PID_231A\MSFT30NAC25CA9
Hardware IDs             : USB\VID_0BC2&PID_231A&REV_0710 USB\VID_0BC2&PID_231A
Driver KeyName           : {4d36e97b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001 (GUID_DEVCLASS_SCSIADAPTER)
Driver                   : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\uaspstor.sys (Version: 10.0.19041.1023  Date: 2021-06-27)
Driver Inf               : C:\WINDOWS\inf\uaspstor.inf
Legacy BusType           : PNPBus
Class                    : SCSIAdapter
Class GUID               : {4d36e97b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} (GUID_DEVCLASS_SCSIADAPTER)
Service                  : UASPStor
Enumerator               : USB
Location Info            : Port_#0002.Hub_#0007
Location IDs             : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1602)#USBROOT(0)#USB(2), ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(UHC6)#USBROOT(0)#USB(2)
Container ID             : {d7c61337-0c5f-5445-b3f6-b084fcfcf042}
Manufacturer Info        : Per USB angeschlossenes SCSI (UAS)-kompatibles Gerät
Capabilities             : 0x14 (Removable, UniqueID)
Status                   : 0x0180600A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_DISABLEABLE, DN_REMOVABLE, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
HcDisableSelectiveSuspend: 0
EnableSelectiveSuspend   : 0
SelectiveSuspendEnabled  : 0
EnhancedPowerMgmtEnabled : 0
IdleInWorkingState       : 0
WakeFromSleepState       : 0
Power State              : D0 (supported: D0, D2, D3, wake from D0, wake from D2)
 Child Device 1          : Seagate Expansion SCSI Disk Device (Laufwerk)
  Device ID              : SCSI\DISK&VEN_SEAGATE&PROD_EXPANSION\6&1EC56E78&0&000000
  Class                  : DiskDrive
  Driver KeyName         : {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0002 (GUID_DEVCLASS_DISKDRIVE)
  Service                : disk
  Location               : Bus Number 0, Target Id 0, LUN 0

        +++++++++++++++++ Registry USB Flags +++++++++++++++++
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\0BC2231A0710
 osvc                    : REG_BINARY 00 00

        ---------------- Connection Information ---------------
Connection Index         : 0x02 (Port 2)
Connection Status        : 0x01 (DeviceConnected)
Current Config Value     : 0x01 (Configuration 1)
Device Address           : 0x01 (1)
Is Hub                   : 0x00 (no)
Device Bus Speed         : 0x02 (High-Speed)
Number Of Open Pipes     : 0x04 (4 pipes to data endpoints)
Pipe[0]                  : EndpointID=1  Direction=OUT  ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Bulk
Pipe[1]                  : EndpointID=2  Direction=IN   ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Bulk
Pipe[2]                  : EndpointID=3  Direction=IN   ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Bulk
Pipe[3]                  : EndpointID=4  Direction=OUT  ScheduleOffset=0  Type=Bulk
Data (HexDump)           : 02 00 00 00 12 01 10 02 00 00 00 40 C2 0B 1A 23   ...........@...#
                           10 07 01 02 03 01 01 02 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 01   ................
                           00 00 00 07 05 01 02 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 07 05   ................
                           82 02 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 07 05 83 02 00 02 00   ................
                           00 00 00 00 07 05 04 02 00 02 00 00 00 00 00      ...............

        --------------- Connection Information V2 -------------
Connection Index         : 0x02 (2)
Length                   : 0x10 (16 bytes)
SupportedUsbProtocols    : 0x03
 Usb110                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 1.1)
 Usb200                  : 1 (yes, port supports USB 2.0)
 Usb300                  : 0 (no, port not supports USB 3.0)
 ReservedMBZ             : 0x00
Flags                    : 0x02
 DevIsOpAtSsOrHigher     : 0 (Device is not operating at SuperSpeed or higher)
 DevIsSsCapOrHigher      : 1 (Device is SuperSpeed capable or higher)
 DevIsOpAtSsPlusOrHigher : 0 (Device is not operating at SuperSpeedPlus or higher)
 DevIsSsPlusCapOrHigher  : 0 (Device is not SuperSpeedPlus capable or higher)
 ReservedMBZ             : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 02 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00   ................

    ---------------------- Device Descriptor ----------------------
bLength                  : 0x12 (18 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x01 (Device Descriptor)
bcdUSB                   : 0x210 (USB Version 2.10)
bDeviceClass             : 0x00 (defined by the interface descriptors)
bDeviceSubClass          : 0x00
bDeviceProtocol          : 0x00
bMaxPacketSize0          : 0x40 (64 bytes)
idVendor                 : 0x0BC2 (Seagate Technology LLC)
idProduct                : 0x231A
bcdDevice                : 0x0710
iManufacturer            : 0x01 (String Descriptor 1)
 Language 0x0409         : "Seagate"
iProduct                 : 0x02 (String Descriptor 2)
 Language 0x0409         : "Expansion"
iSerialNumber            : 0x03 (String Descriptor 3)
 Language 0x0409         : "NAC25CA9"
bNumConfigurations       : 0x01 (1 Configuration)
Data (HexDump)           : 12 01 10 02 00 00 00 40 C2 0B 1A 23 10 07 01 02   .......@...#....
                           03 01                                             ..

    ------------------ Configuration Descriptor -------------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x02 (Configuration Descriptor)
wTotalLength             : 0x0055 (85 bytes)
bNumInterfaces           : 0x01 (1 Interface)
bConfigurationValue      : 0x01 (Configuration 1)
iConfiguration           : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
bmAttributes             : 0x80
 D7: Reserved, set 1     : 0x01
 D6: Self Powered        : 0x00 (no)
 D5: Remote Wakeup       : 0x00 (no)
 D4..0: Reserved, set 0  : 0x00
MaxPower                 : 0xFA (500 mA)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 02 55 00 01 01 00 80 FA 09 04 00 00 02 08 06   ..U.............
                           50 00 07 05 81 02 00 02 00 07 05 02 02 00 02 00   P...............
                           09 04 00 01 04 08 06 62 00 07 05 01 02 00 02 00   .......b........
                           04 24 01 00 07 05 82 02 00 02 00 04 24 02 00 07   .$..........$...
                           05 83 02 00 02 00 04 24 03 00 07 05 04 02 00 02   .......$........
                           00 04 24 04 00                                    ..$..

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x00
bAlternateSetting        : 0x00
bNumEndpoints            : 0x02 (2 Endpoints)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x08 (Mass Storage)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x06 (SCSI transparent command set)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x50 (Bulk-Only Transport)
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 00 00 02 08 06 50 00                        .......P.

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x81 (Direction=IN EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0200 (max 512 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 81 02 00 02 00                              .......

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x02 (Direction=OUT EndpointID=2)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0200 (max 512 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 02 02 00 02 00                              .......

        ---------------- Interface Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x04 (Interface Descriptor)
bInterfaceNumber         : 0x00
bAlternateSetting        : 0x01
bNumEndpoints            : 0x04 (4 Endpoints)
bInterfaceClass          : 0x08 (Mass Storage)
bInterfaceSubClass       : 0x06 (SCSI transparent command set)
bInterfaceProtocol       : 0x62 (USB Attached SCSI - UAS)
iInterface               : 0x00 (No String Descriptor)
Data (HexDump)           : 09 04 00 01 04 08 06 62 00                        .......b.

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x01 (Direction=OUT EndpointID=1)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0200 (max 512 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 01 02 00 02 00                              .......

        ------------- UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor ---------------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor)
bPipeID                  : 0x01 (Pipe ID=1)
bReserved                : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 04 24 01 00                                       .$..

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x82 (Direction=IN EndpointID=2)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0200 (max 512 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 82 02 00 02 00                              .......

        ------------- UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor ---------------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor)
bPipeID                  : 0x02 (Pipe ID=2)
bReserved                : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 04 24 02 00                                       .$..

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x83 (Direction=IN EndpointID=3)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0200 (max 512 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 83 02 00 02 00                              .......

        ------------- UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor ---------------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor)
bPipeID                  : 0x03 (Pipe ID=3)
bReserved                : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 04 24 03 00                                       .$..

        ----------------- Endpoint Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x05 (Endpoint Descriptor)
bEndpointAddress         : 0x04 (Direction=OUT EndpointID=4)
bmAttributes             : 0x02 (TransferType=Bulk)
wMaxPacketSize           : 0x0200 (max 512 bytes)
bInterval                : 0x00 (never NAKs)
Data (HexDump)           : 07 05 04 02 00 02 00                              .......

        ------------- UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor ---------------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x24 (UAS Pipe Usage Descriptor)
bPipeID                  : 0x04 (Pipe ID=4)
bReserved                : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 04 24 04 00                                       .$..

    ----------------- Device Qualifier Descriptor -----------------
bLength                  : 0x0A (10 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x06 (Device_qualifier Descriptor)
bcdUSB                   : 0x210 (USB Version 2.10)
bDeviceClass             : 0x00 (defined by the interface descriptors)
bDeviceSubClass          : 0x00
bDeviceProtocol          : 0x00
bMaxPacketSize0          : 0x40 (64 Bytes)
bNumConfigurations       : 0x01 (1 other-speed configuration)
bReserved                : 0x00
Data (HexDump)           : 0A 06 10 02 00 00 00 40 01 00                     .......@..

      ---------- Binary Object Store (BOS) Descriptor -----------
bLength                  : 0x05 (5 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x0F (Binary Object Store)
wTotalLength             : 0x0016 (22 bytes)
bNumDeviceCaps           : 0x02
Data (HexDump)           : 05 0F 16 00 02                                    .....

        ------------- USB 2.0 Extension Descriptor ------------
bLength                  : 0x07 (7 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x10 (Device Capability Descriptor)
bDevCapabilityType       : 0x02 (USB 2.0 Extension)
bmAttributes             : 0xF0E
 LPMCapable              : 1 (Link Power Management protocol is supported)
 BESLAndAlternateHIRD    : 1 (BESL & Alternate HIRD definitions are supported)
 BaselineBESLValid       : 1 (valid)
 DeepBESLValid           : 0 (not valid)
 BaselineBESL            : 15 (10000 µs)
 DeepBESL                : 0
Data (HexDump)           : 07 10 02 0E 0F 00 00                              .......

        ----- SuperSpeed USB Device Capability Descriptor -----
bLength                  : 0x0A (10 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x10 (Device Capability Descriptor)
bDevCapabilityType       : 0x03 (SuperSpeed USB Device Capability)
bmAttributes             : 0x00
 Bit 0 Reserved          : 0x00
 Bit 1 LTM Capable       : 0x00 (no)
 Bit 7:2 Reserved        : 0x00
wSpeedsSupported         : 0x0E (Full-Speed, High-Speed, SuperSpeed)
bFunctionalitySupport    : 0x01 (lowest speed with all the functionality is 'Full-Speed')
bU1DevExitLat            : 0x0A   (less than 10 µs)
wU2DevExitLat            : 0x0020 (less than 32 µs)
Data (HexDump)           : 0A 10 03 00 0E 00 01 0A 20 00                     ........ .

      -------------------- String Descriptors -------------------
             ------ String Descriptor 0 ------
bLength                  : 0x04 (4 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language ID[0]           : 0x0409 (English - United States)
Data (HexDump)           : 04 03 09 04                                       ....
             ------ String Descriptor 1 ------
bLength                  : 0x10 (16 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "Seagate"
Data (HexDump)           : 10 03 53 00 65 00 61 00 67 00 61 00 74 00 65 00   ..S.e.a.g.a.t.e.
             ------ String Descriptor 2 ------
bLength                  : 0x14 (20 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "Expansion"
Data (HexDump)           : 14 03 45 00 78 00 70 00 61 00 6E 00 73 00 69 00   ..E.x.p.a.n.s.i.
                           6F 00 6E 00                                       o.n.
             ------ String Descriptor 3 ------
bLength                  : 0x12 (18 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x03 (String Descriptor)
Language 0x0409          : "NAC25CA9"
Data (HexDump)           : 12 03 4E 00 41 00 43 00 32 00 35 00 43 00 41 00   ..N.A.C.2.5.C.A.
                           39 00                                             9.
```

### Questions

1. What does it mean, when the disk gets listed in the device manager, but not in Windows nor disk management?
2. How can I make my disk visible in Windows again and access the data on the disk?

Comment: Do you mean 

Just a few days ago, Windows did recognize the USB disk (also on my second pc and smart tv). Also in Windows disk management, the disk does not show up.

Comment: Do you mean "BUT in Windows disk management, the disk does not show up."? If you say "also" one would expect the same behaviour in Windows disk management, so there would be no issue to complain. You might consider correcting your statement so that your problem becomes visible. "Also" is confusing.

Comment: @r2d3 Yes, a few days ago, Windows did recognize the USB disk. However, I needed to unplug und replug it after every Windwos start for it to work properly. But today, the disk does neither show up in Windows, nor disk management, just in the USB Tree Viewer. I updated my question accordingly to make it more clear, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Your title "USB harddisk does not get recognized by Windows anymore at all" contradicts  "It does get listed in the device manager, however:" Generally I usually ignore such postings. As I can't examine your machine physically I depend on precise descriptions. Your title suggests using a professional recovery service. The content does not necessary lead to that conclusion. Furthermore, there is no question that you are asking.

Comment: @r2d3 You are absolutely right. I updated my entry accordingly such that it also has questions now which I would be very glad to have some answers to. Thank you for giving me a chance to improve.

Comment: No that is a pretty weird situation. What is the complete name of your operating system? "Windows" is not specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lucky, the next day, after trying several times unplugging and replugging it, removing it from the device manager, waiting for Windows to add it again. Finally just left it plugged in for a while, all of a sudden, it appeared again.

However, when doing a backup, some files were unable to copy. So I am sure this is a hardware issue and will replace the disk.

Just interesting, when looking at disk health with CrystalDiskInfo, there is no information to display:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your disk is recognized using a different machine or a different operating system.

Comment: Thanks, I did. Same problem there.